Error while deploying smart contract using web3.js
I'm using the below JS code utilizing the web3.js package to deploy a smart contract using the ABI and BIN files, but getting an error as:
Transaction processing could not be completed due to an exception

I am not having any clue why is it failing. Any help would be appreciated.
JS code:
import { Web3 } from 'web3';
import path from 'path';
import fs from 'fs';
import { Transaction as Tx } from 'ethereumjs-tx';

const web3 = new Web3('HTTP://127.0.0.1:8546');

const privateKey =
    "0x8f2a55949038a9610f50fb23b5883af3b4ecb3c3bb792cbcefbd1542c692be63";
const privateKeyBuffer = Buffer.from(privateKey.slice(2), 'hex');
const account = web3.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount(privateKey);

//const contractJson = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./SimpleStorage.json"));
//console.log("contractJson is:",contractJson);
const contractAbi = fs.readFileSync("./SimpleStorage_sol_SimpleStorage.abi");
//const contractAbi = contractJson.abi;
console.log("contractAbi is:",contractAbi);

const contractBin = fs.readFileSync("./SimpleStorage_sol_SimpleStorage.bin");
console.log("contractBin is:",contractBin);

// initialize the default constructor with a value `47 = 0x2F`; this value is appended to the bytecode
const contractConstructorInit =
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002F";

// get txnCount for the nonce value
const txnCount = await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(account.address);
console.log("txnCount:", web3.utils.numberToHex(txnCount));

const chainId = await web3.eth.getChainId();
console.log("ChainId:", web3.utils.numberToHex(chainId));

const rawTxOptions = {
    nonce: web3.utils.numberToHex(txnCount),
    from: account.address,
    to: null, //public tx
    value: "0x00",
    data: "0x" + contractBin + contractConstructorInit, // contract binary appended with initialization value
    gasPrice: "0x0", //ETH per unit of gas
    gasLimit: "0x24A22", //max number of gas units the tx is allowed to use
};
console.log("Creating transaction...");
const tx = new Tx(rawTxOptions);


console.log("Signing transaction...");
tx.sign(privateKeyBuffer);
console.log("Sending transaction...");

try {
    var serializedTx = tx.serialize();
    console.log("serializedTx is:", serializedTx.toString("hex").toString("hex"));
    const pTx = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(
        "0x" + serializedTx.toString("hex").toString("hex"),
    );
    console.log("Response is:", pTx);
    console.log("tx transactionHash: " + pTx.transactionHash);
    console.log("tx contractAddress: " + pTx.contractAddress);
} catch (error) {
    console.error("Transaction failed!");

    // Check if error contains specific revert information
    if (error.receipt) {
        console.error("Transaction Receipt:", error.receipt);
        console.error("Transaction hx failed:", error.receipt.transactionHash);
        console.error("Revert Reason:", await getRevertReason(error.receipt.transactionHash));
    } else {
        console.error("Error Details:", error);
    }
}

/**
* Helper function to get the revert reason from a transaction hash.
*/
async function getRevertReason(txHash) {
    const receipt = await web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(txHash);
    if (!receipt) {
        return "Receipt not found.";
    }
    const result = await web3.eth.call({
        to: receipt.to,
        data: receipt.input,
    }, receipt.blockNumber);
    if (result && result.startsWith("0x08c379a")) {
        const reason = web3.utils.toAscii(result.substr(138));
        return reason || "No revert reason provided";
    }
    return "No reason provided.";
}

Smart Contract:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0

pragma solidity ^0.8.28;


contract SimpleStorage {

    uint256 number;

    /**
     * @dev Store value in variable
     * @param num value to store
     */
    function store(uint256 num) public {
        number = num;
    }

    /**
     * @dev Return value 
     * @return value of 'number'
     */
    function retrieve() public view returns (uint256){
        return number;
    }
}

ABI:
[{"inputs":[],"name":"retrieve","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"num","type":"uint256"}],"name":"store","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"}]

BIN:
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


Can you add the SimpleStorage contract code as well, whose abi and bin files you're accessing?

Hello @SYEDASADKAZMI edited and added contract

If the contractAbi or contractBin file content is invalid or improperly read, the transaction will fail. Can you share the abi file also , and smartcontract.

Hello Aditya, edited and added abi, bin in description.
